# What do I use for $k$ in the definition for the $k$th moment of a distribution?

Tags: statistics, summation, mathematical-physics, random, uniform-distribution

I'm trying to test the logistic map $x_{i+1}=\mu x_i (1-x_i)$ for randomness. To do this, I need to set $\mu=4$ and then use this randomness test:

[image]

However, I don't understand what the $k$th moment means. I see that the summation is over $i$, so then what does the $k$ signify in the summation?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe I should reword my question. What do I use for $k$ here? In the summation, it looks like I need to raise $x_i$ to the $k$th power. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: $k$-th moment is just $\int_\Bbb R x^k dF_X(x)$ and in your case it's just $\frac1n\sum_1^n x_i^k$.

Comment: @Vim I see that, yes, but what value does $k$ represent? 5? 27? 20009193? Or does it not represent any value?

Comment: it doesn't represent any specific value. You can take any one as you like.

Answer (score 1):

You get to choose $k$.  Each different $k$ gives a different test.  You can average the squares of the $x_i$ with $k=2$, average the tenth powers with $k=10$ or whatever you like.  The point is that if $P(x)=1$ the integral is as stated for each $k$.  If the $x$s are biased high, the integral will be higher that that.  If the $x$s are biased low, the integral will be lower.  Once you write a program to do this, it is easy to accumulate the data for a number of $k$s at once and  compute the average.

As an aside, I claim it is a serious error to state that meeting this criterion means your generator is uniform or random.  If the generator is uniform you will satisfy this, but (for any fixed set of $k$s) there are nonuniform distributions that will also satisfy it.  Testing whether the distribution varies as $1/{\sqrt N}$ is very problematic, so using it for testing randomness (however defined) is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I think one direction of the implication is fine.  Uniform implies the $k$th moment is as stated, but not the other way.  If I have a distribution with $2/3$ of the $x_i$ zero and the other $1/3$ being $1$ I will pass the second moment test.  I could make a discrete distribution with more points to pass any finite set of moment tests, but it would not be uniform as it would have no points in between.  Then if the points are always distributed $0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,\ldots$ I claim they are not random